# Hazelcast not loading distributed map entries

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

we are using Hazelcast distributed map in our project.
After a delivery, **it simply stopped reading from the Database the entries**. Storing works. Locally we couldn't reproduce the problem.

We tried restarting the server or emptying the database table but didn't worked. The map is always empty:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hazelcast")
    private transient HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;
    ....
    hazelcastInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME).keySet() ;//is empty
```

The Hazelcast configuration for the map:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcast">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:group name="${hazelcast.clustername}" password="${hazelcast.password}" />
            <hz:properties>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.jmx">${hazelcast.jmx:true}</hz:property>
            </hz:properties>
            <hz:network port="${hazelcast.port:8801}"
                port-auto-increment="${hazelcast.auto-increment:true}">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="${hazelcast.multicast-enabled:false}"
                        multicast-group="${hazelcast.multicast-group}"
                        multicast-port="${hazelcast.multicast-port}" />
                    <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${hazelcast.tcp-ip-enabled:true}">
                        <hz:members>${hazelcast.tcp-ip-members}</hz:members>
                    </hz:tcp-ip>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>    
<hz:map name="maps.*" backup-count="2" max-size="0" eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true" eviction-policy="NONE" merge-policy="com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy">
            <hz:map-store enabled="true" write-delay-seconds="0" implementation="persistenceProvider"/>
        </hz:map>
```

Our application is Spring based. The PersistenceProvider class simply implements the com.hazelcast.core.MapLoader and com.hazelcast.core.MapStore in order to process the entries within the database.

```
@Component
public class PersistenceProvider implements MapLoader<Key, Value>, MapStore<Key, Value> {...}
```

In the logs I only saw this entry that maybe is or not relevant:

```
[hz._hzInstance_1_Cluster.cached.thread-2] INFO  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector.log | [xxx]:8801 Could not connect to: /yyy:8802. Reason: SocketException[Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /yyyy:8802]
[hz._hzInstance_1_Cluster.cached.thread-2] INFO  c.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.log | [xxx]:8801 [xxx]:8802 is added to the blacklist.
```

As a reminder: the code worked before, works locally but now on this environment only stores hazelcast data but doesn't load it!

I am new to Hazelcast and I was wondering if it might be some cache issue or something that we can change within the configuration.

It is important to unblock this as the customer cannot use the application.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with MapLoader's database connection since you state MapStore works, and Maploader also works in your local. Have you checked hazelcast member logs for any kind of database connection problem? Feel free to share maploader impl. and those logs, if any.

Comment: After a redeployment of the app, seemed to be working again. That is really strange. Before it was just server restart. How can that be?

Comment: Hmm, I'd check for database connectivity and the part in your implementation regarding that.